# The method Files.get does not return the full file response

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I use [google-drive-api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3) from this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).

But I find my response is different from the api website.

My response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1hs6V6eDa6CYd3gtkAeRKlrOezLYpDWTfWh5VFtchFYA",
 "name": "Test001",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
}
```

You can see it:

[image]

But the documented [file response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) object is very detailed.

Why are these two response results different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally by default, the server sends back the full representation of a resource after processing requests. For better performance, you can ask the server to send only the fields you really need and get a [partial response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response) instead.

Google Drive api v3 has partial response enabled for most of the methods by default. To request a partial response, use the fields request parameter to specify the fields you want returned. You can use this parameter with any request that returns response data.

Example:

returns only Kind, items.title,

```
&fields=kind,items(title)
```

or

Returns everything

```
&fields=*
```

Tip: In the try me click `Show standard parameters` you will be able to add fields

Comment: I didn't click `Show standard parameters`,after click, I found what you said.Thanks!